# What happenned to Angron and Corvax between the scattering of the primarch and their discoveries?

Tags: warhammer-40k, horus-heresy

I was reading the warhammer 40k wiki [page](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Primarch) of the primarch when I saw this table:

| Legion Number | Primarch | Legion | Name World of Rediscovery | Date of Rediscovery |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XVIth | Horus | Luna Wolves | Cthonia | 801.M30 |
| VIth | Leman Russ | Space Wolves | Fenris | 819.M30 |
| IInd | RECORDS REDACTED | RECORDS REDACTED | RECORDS REDACTED | RECORDS REDACTED |
| Xth | Ferrus Manus | Iron Hands | Medusa | 824.M30 |
| IIIrd | Fulgrim | Emperor's Children | Chemos | 830.M30 |
| XVIIIth | Vulkan | Salamanders | Nocturne | 832.M30 |
| VIIth | Rogal Dorn | Imperial Fists | Inwit | 835.M30 |
| XIIIth | Roboute Guilliman | Ultramarines | Macragge | 837.M30 |
| XVth | Magnus the Red | Thousand Sons | Prospero | 840.M30 |
| IXth | Sanguinius | Blood Angels | Baal | 843.M30 |
| Ist | Lion El'Jonson | Dark Angels | Caliban | 846.M30 |
| IVth | Perturabo | Iron Warriors | Olympia | 849.M30 |
| XIVth | Mortarion | Death Guard | Barbarus | 854.M30 |
| XVIIth | Lorgar | Word Bearers | Colchis | 857.M30 |
| Vth | Jaghatai Khan | White Scars | Mundus Planus | 865.M30 |
| VIIIth | Konrad Curze | Night Lords | Nostramo | 896.M30 |
| XIIth | Angron | World Eaters | Nuceria | 899.M30 |
| XIXth | Corvus Corax | Raven Guard | Deliverance | 922.M30 |
| XIth | RECORDS REDACTED | RECORDS REDACTED | RECORDS REDACTED | RECORDS REDACTED |
| XXth | Alpharius Omegon | Alpha Legion | Unknown | 981.M30 |

I was wondering what some primarch did during this time. In particular Angron and Corvax who were found particulary late into the crusade but were not in charge of the planets they were dropped off. Was Angron a gladiator for almost a hundred years? Did Corvax stayed in prison for all of this time? Or did the warp dropped him way later than the others?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per *Deliverance Lost* and some other sources, Corvus was raised on the moon Deliverance then leading a rebellion against the enslaver technocrats on the planet below.  He managed to wrap up that situation via dropping things (either rocks or nukes I can't remember) out of the sky onto the technocrats' cities about the same time the Emperor found him.

For Angron (primarily in *After Desh'ea* but from other sources like his primarch book etc) he was a gladiator for decades and then led a gladiator rebellion against the "High Rider" civilzation that enslaved him.  However unlike Corax his rebellion wasn't successful, with Big E teleporting Angron away from his army just before their disastrous final battle against the High Riders that led to his army's annihilation.  Which is the root cause of Angron's.... dislike... of the Emperor and the Imperium.

Based on the (very sketchy) timeline you can piece together from Corax arriving on-planet and Big E arriving only a decade or so passed.  So presumably Corax arrived "late" compared to other primarchs found earlier.  The same thing might be true of Angron though he seems to have spent a lot longer as a gladiator and fighting his slave rebellion than Corax did as a prisoner/rebel leader.

Comment: I will just add that Angron spent a long time apparently on Terra where the Emperor investigated the Butchers Nails and getting them removed. Angron also had that whole "therapy session" with his legions senior officers while he figured out which one was ging to be his commander :). 

RE Corax, he was discovered 10 years before the Emperor found him, there are suggestions that he was in some form of stasis, possibly for decades, before he was found in the middle of the asteroid he was on. Also, while the Emperor discovered him, he left him to continue his task and didn't tell the legion.